# Line break with css

Tags: css, line-breaks

I have 7 divs in a row with all very little content. I want to have the first 3 one a line then the next 3, and so on.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child-a">abc</div>
 <div class="child-b">def</div>
 <div class="child-c">ghi</div>
 <div class="child-d">jkl</div>
 <div class="child-e">mno</div>
 <div class="child-f">pqr</div>
 <div class="child-g">stu</div>
</div>
```

So how can I make this work?

For the first line I have

```
.child-a, .child-b, .child-c {
  padding: 0 2% 0 0;
  width:100%
  display: inline;
  float: left;
 }
```

What would the css be for child-c, child-d, child-e so that they would be displayed below child-a, child-b, child-c rather than on the same line?

My complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/winchendonsprings/UfswL/11/

Comment: Give certain width to parent class.

Comment: Note that `width:100% display: inline;` cancel each other - you're missing a `;`, so neither work. Fortunately, `float: left;` hides this issue. Think about what you're doing - do you really need `float` here? Can you give the children and the parent widths, as  Thilakar suggested? (for example `50px`/`160px` will keep 3 in a line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to go would be something like this.

```
.parent div { float: left; }
.parent div:nth-child(3n + 1) { clear: left; }
```

Every element after the third will go to next line. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tBuzb/1/)

This is do what you asked `the first 3 one a line then the next 3, and so on.` efficiently despites some browsers compatiblity issues.

Comment: Maybe you can give me a hand with the exact code. http://jsfiddle.net/winchendonsprings/b3uwy/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the dots for the classes:

```
.child-a, .child-b, .child-c,
.child-d, .child-e, .child-f,
.child-g, .child-h, .child-i {
    padding: 0 2% 0 0;
    width:100%
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.child-d { clear: left; }
.child-g { clear: left; }
```

This will make it so that 'd' and 'g' can't have a floated element to their left.

Comment: This worked great too. Basically the same as the answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I am getting is you want 3 divs one top row, then 3 divs on second row, then the last two divs on last row. If that is correct, you dont need 7 ID's. Instead use one class.

```
.child_div {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px; /* for beautification */
    float: left;
}
```

All child divs must use this class. The divs will automatically align themselves side by side.

A couple of issues that may arise:

- The parent div will have 0 height because all of it's child divs are floated. To fix this, you can set the parent div's height (does not respond to content length), or set `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;` ("pulls" the child content inside)
- Different browsers may react a little differently. For example for IE, you  need `width:32.5%;` for example because it works a bit different. Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked too. But divs with more content to them didn't look quite as good. Maybe if all the divs had a lot or a little content this would be best. But the divs varied so it kind of looked strange with some lines wrapping and some not. Thanks